# Typescript generic class in object

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to do a generic typescript class. But it doesn't work when the class is inside an object. I've tried a lot of codes, but they don't work for me :(

I have tried all of this.

```js
// this is my class object
const obj1 = {
    Foo: class<T> {
        foo: T

        constructor({ foo }: { foo: T }) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        getFoo(): T {
            return this.foo
        }

        setFoo(t: T): T {
            this.foo = t
            return this.foo
        }
    }
}


// This works: it is typechecked
let a = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
a.getFoo()      // number
a.setFoo('123') // error


// None of this works
// uncomment them to see errors

// let b: obj1.Foo                                      = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: obj1.Foo<number>                              = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo                               = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo<number>                       = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo.prototype                     = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo.prototype<number>             = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1["Foo"]["prototype"]               = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1["Foo"]["prototype"]<number>       = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })


b.getFoo()      // any
b.setFoo('123') // works (it should error instead)
```

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?declaration=false&target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAjDAvDA3gKBnmAYiCAFwzAA2AhhBADwAqAfFrvuwGbFkPZvt5QkKACcArsCggRACkwwuIGAF8y8xTxUBKVgL0woACwCWEAHSL0C4gG5+A5X30wA5gFMoREDK2acz9hEPMREwAxNzRXt2R2j8CA8vGSgeXxgGXQC8I1MLYisoOL0gqBCwnMjiIpV7R1iAenr0iJgAd2kAawgyY1hTAwBPAAc3YENRjrcAE2wKDxgqKzA3VrgkZDMk9W4YAAZtbCozd09iHz1GmDAxAFt4NxFDswTT7wByZAAmAGY3nUuHiJpHxsJcAHLgNxwDjhKFcCgUECtYxgFwLIKDEZjCbTUFNMRgUA3G5uMCwIxuG4GJQJKGA6QQPiXOaweBkBAoTb5LL6ACQPIEGGWqw5Gy21lIewOzPmbLWnK8dGudweLHY-IFPKFK3lYrO20l+2UWjxMBZMDlUGGbhAMNFXKUmqd+G1IvWDrkErIRpNMtZZCtI1tuodStu9xEaudeldIfFGilxtN5st1uD9q8ZiGQKkgah0fYsYz+q9id9TRTAbTdvdmezIFz1rDKsjmqLtZLCZ9ydlVaDNZQAG0AEReYcAXRH9cbIwnzvbCs7O27fotfZtA+QI7Hk+H04b1onzYjUcLVx1xe8Bu9Bz48GOiTOOgElyoYAG2HvLySHx+fxglztCIXQwDIvQwBAhggGIFBTDA9IiDAKLQG4VBTCaQA)

thanks but sorry for bad english

Comment: Hi. For what puprose you include class declaration inside object? If you are trying to achieve namespace logic, then it should be implemented through https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#using-namespaces.

Comment: I want to use namespacing structure, but keep all the namespaces in one single output file

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change it myself @НиколайГольцев

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you can do what you want:

```
namespace customNamespace {
    export class Foo<T> {
        private foo: T;

        constructor({ foo }: { foo: T }) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        getFoo(): T {
            return this.foo;
        }

        setFoo(t: T): T {
            this.foo = t;
            return this.foo;
        }
    }
}

// This works: it is typechecked
let a = new customNamespace.Foo({ foo: 0 });
a.getFoo();      // number
a.setFoo('123'); // error


// None of the following are typechecked
// uncomment them to see errors

// let b: obj1.Foo                                      = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
let b: customNamespace.Foo<number>                              = new customNamespace.Foo({ foo: 0 });
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo                               = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo<number>                       = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo.prototype                     = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1.Foo.prototype<number>             = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1["Foo"]["prototype"]               = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })
// let b: typeof obj1["Foo"]["prototype"]<number>       = new obj1.Foo({ foo: 0 })


b.getFoo()      // old: any, now: typechecked!
b.setFoo('123') // old: works (it should error instead), now: got an error!
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using `namespace`? I would *really* like to keep my current structure (a normal object) if it's possible. Thanks for the alternative, anyways.

Comment: I think no, you can't do that. Because you are trying to use obj1.Foo as a type, but from Typescript's standpoint it's a value and there is no way to denote generic type with it when declare another variable type. So maximum what you can is use typeof obj1.Foo.prototype as a type where generic type would be any, that doesn't make sense.